# Addclass to inactive jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, select, user-interface, tabs

I'm using jQuery UI's tabs widget and its really great and useful although i have one simple question. How can i add a class to all inactive tabs? I have the following code so far and it adds a class to the active tab, Now i want to remove the class from the inactive tabs. How can i achieve this?

```
$("#sidebar").tabs({
    event: "click",
    activate : function(event, ui) { var activeTab = ui.newTab; $(activeTab).addClass(ActiveTab); },
});



            <ul id="sidebar-tabs">
                <li class="tab"><a href="#tab-1"><span>TAB 1</span></a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#tab-2"><span>TAB 2</span></a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#tab-3"><span>TAB 3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML of the tabs so we could help design a selector that would target the inactive tabs.

Comment: Why don't you do the opposite... add a class to all tabs and remove it from the selected one.

Answer (score 2):

As my comment suggested, you can do the opposite... add the class to all tabs by default (or simply style the anchor as is) and remove it from the selected one.

*PS: I edited your HTML code with an example from jQuery UI.*

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UnYx9/3/)

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#sidebar").tabs({
        event: "click",
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var _tab = ui.newTab;
            $('#sidebar li').removeClass('active');
            $(_tab).addClass('active');
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem. But technically, if you do your CSS right you don't nee to add a class to inactive tabs... they should have the default CSS applied. Then on the active tab, it should overwrite the CSS you need. Get it?